# django rest framework " TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable " error

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I do not know what configuration to modify.

My git repository URL is: https://github.com/Nomadcoders-Study/Nomadgram

```
Internal Server Error: /images/all/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/var/pyenv/versions/3.6.1/envs/nomadgram/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/var/pyenv/versions/3.6.1/envs/nomadgram/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/usr/local/var/pyenv/versions/3.6.1/envs/nomadgram/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/var/pyenv/versions/3.6.1/envs/nomadgram/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/var/pyenv/versions/3.6.1/envs/nomadgram/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/var/pyenv/versions/3.6.1/envs/nomadgram/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 478, in dispatch
request = self.initialize_request(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/var/pyenv/versions/3.6.1/envs/nomadgram/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 380, in initialize_request
authenticators=self.get_authenticators(),
  File "/usr/local/var/pyenv/versions/3.6.1/envs/nomadgram/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 274, in get_authenticators
  return [auth() for auth in self.authentication_classes]
TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable
```

Comment: You might need to initiate [`this variable`](https://github.com/Nomadcoders-Study/Nomadgram/blob/master/django_app/config/settings.py#L82-L84) as a `tuple` instead of a string.

Comment: Oh...!!!! Thank you very much!!
Thanks to that, I can solve the problem well.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

On the **settings.py** file append comma at the end of `'...JSONWebTokenAuthentication'` line as below:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
    ),
}
```

**Attention:** without comma this is not a tuple

Comment: 100 likes for telling: "Attention: without comma this is not a tuple"